# Neo4j-Bloodhound- Match Cypher querys between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bloodhound

I am looking for a way to display the direct relation between computers without displaying the users or groups.
Like for example

`MATCH c=(C:Computer)-[:HasSession|:AdminTo|:CanRDP]-(n:Computer)  return c`

The goal is to show the possible connections to other computers based on the users and groups that have access to the computers.

Which relation is used does not matter in the end.

Comment: what is the question? Is there an error or does not meet your expected result? Please show us your problem when you run that query.

Comment: I question is how a query should look like where start and end node are from the same object but not pointing to itself.
So what would a query look like to create a direct connection between "computer" nodes.
For the above query I get no result and also no error message back.

Answer (score 0):

You need virtual relationships to do that in Neo4j . see https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/

Comment: Okay thanks!
I will try this out. 

Or are there graph databases that are better suited for such queries?

Comment: this is not something that depends on the graph database. Some things are solved by the db engine, other things are solved by virtualization or in the visualiastion layer.